Return correct errorType from lambda query type Amplify Data Gen 2
I am building an application with Amplify Gen 2 with Amplify Data.
I am using lambda query handlers for custom queries that return a custom data type for certain tasks. I am using typescript and the handler won't return anything other than the desired data type.
I want the errors array returned by my query on the frontend to contain errors with the errorType I specify and and the correct message.
At the moment, the correct message is always returned whether I throw a custom error class or use callback(error, null). However, the errorType shown on the frontend is always Lambda:Unhandled.
I have tried using an error subclass called CustomError when throwing the error message.
I have also tried passing this error to the callback function like callback(error, null).
Both solutions result in the correct error message, but the errorType always remains Lambda:Unhandled.
I'm looking for a solution to return the correct errorType to make frontend error handling simpler.
